# Two spaceships on collision course with cannonballs

Tags: collision, space

Imagine two spaceships with a cylinder shape, travelling next to each other at the same speed.

4 cannonballs are exactly in their travelling path and they are about to get hit by them.

One of the spaceship's commander sends a crew member to the front in order to catch the cannonball with two springs he shall mount to the front.

Then he mounts each of the springs to the sides of the spaceship and turns them, such that the two cannonballs point towards the back. He then releases the springs and the cannonballs shoot back.

The cannonballs are 1/100th of the weight of the spaceship and the ship is traveling at 100 m/s relative to the cannonballs just in case anyone HAS to know.

Questions: Will the ships afterwards have the same velocity or not? Will the ship, the two springs were used on, reach it's initial velocity after releasing the cannonballs?

If it does not slow, then how could we implement this with an airplane and air molecules hitting the plane in a similar way?

Answer (score 2):

The ship and cannonballs will both have the same velocity in the end. The easiest way to think about this from a reference frame in which the ship is stationary before it intersects the cannonballs. The cannonballs will be moving toward the ship in this frame. When the cannonballs reach the springs on the ship their kinetic energy will be converted into potential energy and the ship/cannonball system will start to move backwards slowly. When the ship releases the cannonballs they will regain all their initial kinetic energy (assuming the springs are perfectly elastic) and, from conservation of momentum, we can easily see that the ship has to once again be stationary.

I am a bit confused about what happens to the 2nd ship in your hypothetical situation. If it simply collides with the other two cannonballs it velocity is going change but the details of the change will depend on the details of the collision.

Comment: Can you show how you would arrive at that answer by considering the conservation of momentum and energy before and after the cannonballs were trapped by the springs? And finally after they are released?

Comment: I don't have time to write out the math out explicitly right now but if everything is constrained to one dimension there is only one configuration of velocities of the three bodies that yields a given kinetic energy and momentum. Since the kinetic energy and momentum of the system is the same after the interaction as it was at the start the velocities must also be the same.